# In Windows (10 specifically) why can a user stop or start a service via services.msc but if attempting to do this via cmd require an elevated shell?

Tags: windows, services, elevation

As the title suggests. I had a user who has rights to open services.msc and can start/stop/edit the services with no issue via the GUI.

User cannot script the starting of a service (e.g. "net start SERVICENAME") however because it requires an elevated admin cmd to run these commands. I was just wondering how to explain this behavior?

I don't know if this is unique to Windows 10 but I am not able to try other releases.

Comment: On my system, when starting services.msc it specifically asks for administrative rights before it starts, and if I select no, it doesn't start. So the user must have administrative rights and maybe UAC disabled.

Comment: Same here and on Windows 11 as well. Standard User can start services.msc  but any attempt to Start or Stop any Service is greyed out and disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, Services.msc *is* actually running elevated/as an administrator. By default on Windows 7 and later, users who are local administrators only see elevation prompts for programs outside a Windows-controlled allowed list; programs on the allowed list, which I believe does include Services.msc, will be auto-elevated without any prompt.

You can check this by creating a local user who isn't an administrator and seeing if you can launch Services as that user without entering an administrator's username and password.

Comment: User is most definitely not a local administrator unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, well I should probably withdraw my answer then. Just to make sure, what does `whoami /all` say under Group Information? Does it have an entry for BUILTIN\Administrators (S-1-5-32-544)?